# Background Gradient In Footer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, background, footer, gradient

Q1. How do I add a background image to the footer of my website [markgilvey.com](http://www.markgilvey.com)

My footer is an include file in case that matters.

Q2. I would like to add a gradient behind the footer; would this be made in Photoshop or is there code to do this now-days?

Comment: Better you show the code ...

Answer (score 1):

you could use css to add a background image the height of your footer and repeat horizontally`background: url(someimage.xyz) repeat-x;`

re. creating a gradient, there are genrators out there, such as http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/